# Solving system of equations with Root

Tags: equation-solving

I have this system of equations. I want to express all variables in terms of `x` as you can see. `x` is a parameter.

```
Solve[{y (z - x) == x^6, x zg - z zg == x z^2 za zb - x z za zb zg, 
za zg - zb zg == z za zb - z za^2 zb, zb - zg == z za zb - z zb^2, 
za zb (z - zg) == zg (-zb + zg), za > 0, zb > 0, zg > 0, z > 0}, {y, za, zb, zg, z}, Reals]
```

However *Mathematica* doesn't know how to solve it. Solutions show me something called `Root` and I can't make sense out of any of the expressions I get. What I get is:

```
y -> ConditionalExpression[((
x^6)/(-x + 
Root[-x + 
2 x^2 + (1 - 3 x - x^2) #1 + (1 + 2 x - 4 x^2) #1^2 + (-1 + 
 5 x - x^2) #1^3 + (-1 + x - x^2) #1^4 + x^2 #1^5 &, 3]))
```

I also tried using reduce which gives me a set of solutions for `y`:

```
y == Root[
x^26 + (-x^18 + x^19 - x^20 + 5 x^21) #1 + (-x^12 + x^13 + 3 x^14 - 
   4 x^15 + 10 x^16) #1^2 + (x^6 - x^7 + 5 x^8 + 3 x^9 - 6 x^10 + 
   10 x^11) #1^3 + (1 - x + 3 x^3 + x^4 - 4 x^5 + 
   5 x^6) #1^4 + (-1 + x) #1^5 &, 1]
```

I've read this thread: [How do I work with Root objects?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13767/how-do-i-work-with-root-objects) but it doesn't solve my problem since I have this free parameter `x` that ruins everything. For example if I try `ToRadicals` or numerical value I don't get anything.
How do I make sense of it? How can I proceed to get the full expression for `y` in terms of `x` without `Root`? I tried `FindInstance` but it doesn't work in my case since I have this free parameter `x`. If this helps I'm only interested in `y`, the rest of the parameters don't really matter. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `Root` part is a root to a 5th degree polynomial. In general, they cannot be expressed in terms of radicals. Whether or not your particular solution can, for all `x`, is not a question I can figure out in my head. Probably not, though. One can probably solve it with [this](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/158/), which I believe [solves it in terms of theta functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuinticEquation.html).  But `Root` is probably easier to work with.

Comment: How do I work with Root? Can I for example express y-solution==0 without Root?

Comment: `Root[]` is like any other numeric function such as `Sin[]`.  There are algorithms to compute their values to any number of decimals, there are algorithms for simplifying and combining them.  Just treat like you would `f[x]`. -- Your 2nd question confuses me: Do you want to work with `Root` or without it? If without, see my first comment.

Comment: About 2nd question: I want to eliminate Root so I can have closed expression for y[x] or for example y^2[x] or y^n[x] for any n is good enough. Is this possible?

Comment: What both Michael and the answer you reference are saying is that it is not possible to express the roots of a general 5th order polynomial in terms of radicals.  `Root` represents a number and you can manipulate it symbolically like any other number.

Comment: As I said, see my first comment.  Perhaps it can be done "in terms of theta functions" (link above). -- Related perhaps: [(109578)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109578/writing-mathematicas-root-function-output-in-a-academic-paper-form), not a solution, just relevant to learning to live with `Root` as a closed-form expression.

Comment: Think twice about *why* you want an explicit expression in terms of `x`. Can you do what you want without an explicit form?  In many cases explicit forms are not necessary.

Comment: I can't do what I want without explicit form in terms of x. As I said: I want to have algebraic curve defined by zero locus of some polynomial y^n-solution = 0. So any power of y would work, as long as It's a closed expression even with square root or something (If I would have expression with square root then I could manipulate it to get what I want). Unfortunately a method from the last link on Roots (the one on how to live with them) doesn't give me a nice expression like it gives there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [a comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133297/solving-system-of-equations-with-root#comment359570_133297), it seems maybe the OP would like to rationalize the expression:

```
Product[y - 
   Root[x^26 + (-x^18 + x^19 - x^20 + 5 x^21) #1 + (-x^12 + x^13 + 
         3 x^14 - 4 x^15 + 10 x^16) #1^2 + (x^6 - x^7 + 5 x^8 + 
         3 x^9 - 6 x^10 + 10 x^11) #1^3 + (1 - x + 3 x^3 + x^4 - 
         4 x^5 + 5 x^6) #1^4 + (-1 + x) #1^5 &, i], {i, 
   5}] // FullSimplify
(*
(1/(-1 + x))(x^26 + x^18 (-1 + x - x^2 + 5 x^3) y + 
  x^12 (-1 + x (1 + x (3 + 2 x (-2 + 5 x)))) y^2 + 
  x^6 (1 + x (-1 + x (5 + x (3 + 2 x (-3 + 5 x))))) y^3 + (1 - x + 
     3 x^3 + x^4 - 4 x^5 + 5 x^6) y^4 + (-1 + x) y^5)
*)
```

Set this equal to zero to represent the locus. Note that the product may or may not have introduced extraneous solutions.

---

**Addendum**

Silly me, this is equivalent to, with less work, the following:

```
First[
  Root[x^26 + (-x^18 + x^19 - x^20 + 5 x^21) #1 + (-x^12 + x^13 + 
        3 x^14 - 4 x^15 + 10 x^16) #1^2 + (x^6 - x^7 + 5 x^8 + 
        3 x^9 - 6 x^10 + 10 x^11) #1^3 + (1 - x + 3 x^3 + x^4 - 
        4 x^5 + 5 x^6) #1^4 + (-1 + x) #1^5 &, 1]
  ]@y
(*
x^26 + (-x^18 + x^19 - x^20 + 5 x^21) y + (-x^12 + x^13 + 3 x^14 - 
    4 x^15 + 10 x^16) y^2 + (x^6 - x^7 + 5 x^8 + 3 x^9 - 6 x^10 + 
    10 x^11) y^3 + (1 - x + 3 x^3 + x^4 - 4 x^5 + 5 x^6) y^4 + (-1 + 
    x) y^5
*)
```

There is still the general caveat about rationalizing leads potentially to extraneously solutions.

Comment: That's exactly what I want, I'm really sorry for not being more clear. Thank you very much, you saved the day!

Comment: By the way, there's no extra problem that you mentioned, everything is fine.

Comment: @Caims No problem & you're welcome. I'll leave the warning in case someone else tries the same thing on their problem. It's like squaring both sides of an equation: sometimes you get extra solutions, sometimes not.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you are looking for, but one approach is to define y (and your others) as functions of x and then plot to see what it looks like. For example:

```
y[x_] := Root[x^26 + (-x^18 + x^19 - x^20 + 5 x^21) #1 + 
         (-x^12 + x^13 + 3 x^14 - 4 x^15 + 10 x^16) #1^2 + 
         (x^6 - x^7 + 5 x^8 + 3 x^9 - 6 x^10 + 10 x^11) #1^3 + 
         (1 - x + 3 x^3 + x^4 - 4 x^5 + 5 x^6) #1^4 + (-1 + x) #1^5 &, 1];
Plot[y[x], {x, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the expression for zero locus of the polynomial that I will get from the solution for y.