# Complicated system of nonlinear equations

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic

I'm trying to find a solution to the system of equations:

```
Solve[{y (x z1 z2 z3 z4 - z1 z2 z3 z4 zi zj) == -x^4 zi^2 zj^3, 
x z1 (z1 - z2) == zi (-z1 + zj), 
x z1 z2^2 - x z1 z2 z3 == z1 zj - z2 zj, 
x z2 z3^2 - x z2 z3 z4 == z2 zj - z3 zj, 
x z3 (-1 + z4) z4 == (z3 - z4) zj, (-1 + zi) zi zj == 
x z1 (x - zi zj), zi zj (-z1 + zj) == x^2 z1 z2 z3 z4 (x - zi zj), 
zi > 0, zj > 0, z1 > 0, z2 > 0, z3 > 0, z4 > 0}, {y, z1, z2, z3, z4,
zi, zj}, Reals]
```

I'm only interested in variable `y` in function of `x`. I first tried to use `Reduce` and it took over 15 hours and then I quit. Is there a way to see if solution exists? I tried `alt+,` but there's only a beep sound, no menu comes up. [Solving system of equations with Root](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133297/solving-system-of-equations-with-root) I had a similar system of equations. `Solve` returns the answer after a few seconds and `Reduce` after a few minutes for equations in that thread. Is this example so much more complicated that it will take so much time? Is there a way to solve it within reasonable time? I also tried the reduction to 4 equations for `z1,z2,z3,z4` but the Mathematica can't solve those anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in my earlier answer, and also by the OP in a comment, brute force attempts to obtain a symbolic solution prove unsuccessful.  Nonetheless, a symbolic solution can be obtained by systematically eliminating variables and equations from `eq`.  The key is to assure that the remaining equations are polynomials in the remaining variables.  This can be accomplished by identifying an equation in which a particular variable enters linearly, use that equation to eliminate that variable from the other five equations, and then repeat the process for the remaining five equations.  With luck, this process can be continued until a single polynomial in a single variable remains.  Before starting the process here, it is convenient to simplify the last equation,

```
eq[[7]] = #/(zi zj) & /@ (eq[[7, 1]] == (eq[[7, 2]] /. Flatten@Solve[eq[[6]], z1]))
(* -z1 + zj == x z2 z3 z4 (-1 + zi) *)
```

After that simplification, define and apply

```
g[ind_] := Module[{len = Length[ind], r1, r2, zr1, zr2, zr3, zr4, t},
    r1 = If[len > 0, DeleteCases[Range[2, 7], Alternatives @@ First@Transpose@ind], 
        Range[2, 7]];
    r2 = If[len > 0, DeleteCases[Range[2, 7], Alternatives @@ Last@Transpose@ind], 
        Range[2, 7]]; 
    zr1 = If[len > 0, Solve[eq[[ind[[1, 1]]]], var[[ind[[1, 2]]]]][[1, 1]], {}];
    zr2 = If[len > 1, Solve[eq[[ind[[2, 1]]]] /. zr1, var[[ind[[2, 2]]]]][[1, 1]], {}];
    zr3 = If[len > 2, Solve[eq[[ind[[3, 1]]]] /. zr1 /. zr2, var[[ind[[3, 2]]]]][[1, 1]],
        {}];
    zr4 = If[len > 3, Solve[eq[[ind[[4, 1]]]] /. zr1 /. zr2 /. zr3, 
        var[[ind[[4, 2]]]]][[1, 1]], {}]; 
    t = Outer[{#1, #2, Length@CoefficientList[(Subtract @@ eq[[#1]] /. zr1 /. zr2 /. 
        zr3 /. zr4) // Together // Numerator, var[[#2]]]} &, r1, r2]; 
    Join[ind, #] & /@ Cases[t, {z1_, z2_, 2} -> {{z1, z2}}, {2}]]
```

To see how it works, determine all ways in which a single equation and variable can be eliminated.

```
elim1 = Nest[Flatten[Map[g, #], 1] &, {{}}, 1]
Length[%]
(* {{{2, 3}}, {{2, 6}}, {{2, 7}}, {{3, 2}}, {{3, 4}}, {{3, 7}}, {{4, 3}}, {{4, 5}}, 
    {{4, 7}}, {{5, 4}}, {{5, 7}}, {{6, 2}}, {{6, 7}}, {{7, 2}}, {{7, 3}}, {{7, 4}},
    {{7, 5}}, {{7, 6}}, {{7, 7}}} *)
(* 19 *)
```

`{{2, 3}}`, for instance, indicates that `eq[[2]]` and `var[[3]]` can be eliminated.  In all, there are 19 such possibilities.  Since the goal is to eliminate all but one equation and variable, try

```
elim5 = Nest[Flatten[Map[g, #], 1] &, {{}}, 5]
(* {} *)
```

indicating that five equations and variables cannot be eliminated by linear substitution.  However, there are 464 ways to eliminate four equations and variables, although many are equivalent.

```
elim4 = Nest[Flatten[Map[g, #], 1] &, {{}}, 4]
Length[%]
(* {{{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {6, 2}}, {{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {6, 7}}, ... *)
(* 464 *)
```

The following indicates which sets of four variables can be eliminated and gives representative corresponding sublists from `elim4`.

```
Map[First, GatherBy[elim4, Sort@Last@Transpose@# &]]
var[[#]] & /@ Sort[Sort[#] & /@ (Sort@Last@Transpose@# & /@ %)]
(* {{{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {6, 2}}, {{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {6, 7}}, 
    {{2, 3}, {4, 6}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}}, {{2, 3}, {4, 6}, {3, 2}, {5, 7}}} *)
(* {{z1, z2, z3, z4}, {z1, z2, z3, zi}, {z1, z2, zi, zj}, {z2, z3, z4, zj}} *)
```

In other words, only four of the fifteen possible sets of four variables can be eliminated in this way.  The remaining two equations are obtained from

```
gelim[ind_] := Module[{len = Length[ind], zr1, zr2, zr3, zr4},
    zr1 = If[len > 0, Solve[eq[[ind[[1, 1]]]], var[[ind[[1, 2]]]]][[1, 1]], {}];
    zr2 = If[len > 1, Solve[eq[[ind[[2, 1]]]] /. zr1, var[[ind[[2, 2]]]]][[1, 1]], {}];
    zr3 = If[len > 2, Solve[eq[[ind[[3, 1]]]] /. zr1 /. zr2, var[[ind[[3, 2]]]]][[1, 1]], 
        {}];
    zr4 = If[len > 3, Solve[eq[[ind[[4, 1]]]] /. zr1 /. zr2 /. zr3, 
        var[[ind[[4, 2]]]]][[1, 1]], {}]; 
    DeleteCases[Simplify[Subtract @@ # /. zr1 /. zr2 /. zr3 /. zr4] & /@ eq[[2 ;; 7]], 0]]
```

Applying `gelim` to `{{2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {6, 2}}`,

```
eq4 = gelim[First@elim4];
```

yields two polynomials in `{zi, zj}` that are a bit long to be reproduced here.  The eliminated variables are related to them by

```
gr[ind_] := Module[{len = Length[ind], zr1, zr2, zr3, zr4},
    zr1 = If[len > 0, Solve[eq[[ind[[1, 1]]]], var[[ind[[1, 2]]]]][[1, 1]], {}];
    zr2 = If[len > 1, Solve[eq[[ind[[2, 1]]]] /. zr1, var[[ind[[2, 2]]]]][[1, 1]], {}];
    zr3 = If[len > 2, Solve[eq[[ind[[3, 1]]]] /. zr1 /. zr2, var[[ind[[3, 2]]]]][[1, 1]],
        {}];
    zr4 = If[len > 3, Solve[eq[[ind[[4, 1]]]] /. zr1 /. zr2 /. zr3, 
        var[[ind[[4, 2]]]]][[1, 1]], {}]; 
    Sort@DeleteCases[{zr4, Simplify[zr3 /. zr4], Simplify[zr2 /. zr3 /. zr4], 
        Simplify[zr1 /. zr2 /. zr3 /. zr4]}, {}]]

v4 = gr[First@elim4]
(* {z1 -> ((-1 + zi) zi zj)/(x (x - zi zj)), 
    z2 -> -((x^3 - 2 x^2 zi zj + (-1 + zi) zi zj + 
        x zi (1 + zi (-1 + zj^2)))/(x (-1 + zi) (x - zi zj))), ... *)
```

The required condition that the variables be positive is given by

```
And @@ Simplify[Thread[Greater[var[[2 ;; 5]] /. v4, 0]], x > 0 && zi > 0 && zj > 0];
```

Finally, the solution of `eq4` is obtained in seconds

```
sol = Solve[And @@ Thread[eq4 == 0] && x > 0 && zi > 0 && zj > 0 && %, {zi, zj}, Reals]
Length[sol]
LeafCount[sol]
(* 6 *)
(* 69747 *)
```

It is enormous, consisting of six alternative `ConditionalExpression`s involving up to 25th-order `Root` functions.  Plotting it is fairly straightforward.

```
dta = Transpose@Table[zt = N[Flatten@DeleteCases[sol /. x -> x0, {zi -> Undefined,_}], 45];
    var[[2 ;; 7]] /. Join[v4 /. zt /. x -> x0, zt], {x0, 1/100, 199/100, 1/100}]; 
Table[dta[[i, 100]] = 1, {i, 6}];
ListLinePlot[dta, DataRange -> {1/100, 199/100}, PlotRange -> {0, 1.8}, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[Rest@var, LegendMarkerSize -> 20], {Right, Bottom}]]
```

[image]

`y` can be plotted in a similar manner.

```
ysol = y /. First@Solve[eq[[1]], y]
(* -((x^4 zi^2 zj^3)/(z1 z2 z3 z4 (x - zi zj))) *)
dtay = Table[zt = N[Flatten@DeleteCases[sol /. x -> x0, {zi -> Undefined, _}], 45]; 
    ysol /. v4 /. zt /. x -> x0, {x0, 1/100, 199/100, 1/100}];
ListLinePlot[dtay, DataRange -> {1/100, 199/100}, PlotRange -> {-800, 800}]
```

[image]

To obtain `y` as a function of `x`, use

```
yy[x0_] := First@N[ysol /. v4 /. 
    DeleteCases[sol /. x -> x0, {zi -> Undefined, _}] /. x -> x0]
```

Whether this symbolic solution is more desirable than the numerical solution obtained earlier is a matter of taste.

Comment: It works, thank you. However, I'm looking for variable $y$. This code seems complicated for me. How could I get y from this in terms of Roots and variable x?

Comment: @Caims  It would be an enormously complicated expression.  How do you plan to use the answer?

Comment: I'm going to rationalize it and get expression for y as a zero locus of some polynomial in y and x.

Comment: @Caims `y` is given by `ysol /. v4 /. sol`

Answer (score 5):

Solutions do exist, at least for `x >= 0`.

```
eq = Factor[#] & /@
     {y (x z1 z2 z3 z4 - z1 z2 z3 z4 zi zj) == -x^4 zi^2 zj^3, 
      x z1 (z1 - z2) == zi (-z1 + zj), 
      x z1 z2^2 - x z1 z2 z3 == z1 zj - z2 zj, 
      x z2 z3^2 - x z2 z3 z4 == z2 zj - z3 zj, 
      x z3 (-1 + z4) z4 == (z3 - z4) zj, 
      (-1 + zi) zi zj == x z1 (x - zi zj), 
      zi zj (-z1 + zj) == x^2 z1 z2 z3 z4 (x - zi zj)});
con = {zi > 0, zj > 0, z1 > 0, z2 > 0, z3 > 0, z4 > 0};
var = {y, z1, z2, z3, z4, zi, zj}
```

First, consider the two obvious special cases.

```
Flatten@Simplify[Solve[Flatten@{eq /. x -> 0, con}, var], zj > 0]
(* {y -> 0, z1 -> zj, z2 -> zj, z3 -> zj, z4 -> zj, zi -> 1} *)

Flatten@Solve[Flatten@{eq[[2 ;; 7]] /. x -> 1, con}, var[[2 ;; 7]]];
eq /. x -> 1 /. %
(* {False, True, True, True, True, True, True} *)
```

In other words, `y == 0` for `x == 0`, but there is no solution for `x == 1`.  I have been unable to obtain a symbolic solution for the general case even after 20 hours by

```
Flatten@Solve[Flatten@{eq[[2 ;; 7]], con}, var[[2 ;; 7]]];
Solve[eq[[1]]/.%, y]
```

(Splitting off the solution of `eq[[1]]` is advantageous.)  I have, however, obtained a numerical solutionfor `x > 0`.

```
f[x0_] := Module[{start, s, ys = {y -> 0}, err = True, i = 0},
    While[(Abs[y /. ys] < 1/100 || (zj /. s) < x0/100) && i < 100, i++;
    While[err && i < 100, err = False; i++;
    start = {var[[2 ;; 7]], RandomReal[{1, 5}, 6]} // Transpose;
    s = Quiet@Check[FindRoot[eq[[2 ;; 7]] /. x -> x0, start, MaxIterations -> 1000], 
        err = True]];
    ys = If[err, {y -> 0}, Flatten@Solve[eq[[1]] /. x -> x0 /. s, y]]; 
    If[ys == {}, ys = {y -> 0}]; err = True];
    Join[ys, s]]
```

Although this function is not completely robust, it gives good answers most of the time.

```
dta = Transpose@Table[var /. f[x], {x, .01, 1.99, .01}];
ListPlot[First@dta, DataRange -> {.01, 1.99}, PlotRange -> {-800, 800}]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[Rest@dta, DataRange -> {.01, 1.99}, PlotRange -> {0, 1.8}, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[Rest@var, LegendMarkerSize -> 20], {Right, Bottom}]]
```

[image]

The solution is approximately `y == 1` for small `x`.  Solutions obtained in this way change with `FindRoot` `WorkingPrecision` for `x < 0`, suggesting that no solutions exist there.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. In the meantime I also tried using Maple with eliminate and solve functions, however Maple can't solve this system after a few days of running too. I also tried solving equation by equation in Mathematica but after you eliminate zi and zj it gets impossibly complicated. However, I'm happy that you showed that the solution indeed exists. You can also assume that x>0, but it shouldn't help much.

Answer (score 2):

You may find this useful: You can manually eliminate the first 5 equations

```
e = Fold[((Rest@#1) /. First@Solve[First@#1, #2] // Simplify) &, 
      eq , {y, zi, z1, z2, z4}];
```

This is two nonlinear equations in three unknowns:

```
Union[Cases[ e , _Symbol , Infinity]]
```

> {x, z3, zj}

now you can try:

```
FindInstance[Join[e, { x > 0, z3 > 0 , zj > 0}], {x, z3, zj}]
```

( I didn't let it go very long..so I don't know if it works )

you can try working with  `FindRoot`, etc as well.  If you find a solution then you need to plug back to the original equations and verify your constraints are satisfied.